# Unable to ssh into the aws ec2 instance even after the instance can be ping

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Okay until now I have messed up with my system settings and the AWS settings a lot but here I want to describe my present settings:

**1) My local system :-**

**My system OS : Arch Linux**

**SSH installed : openssh**

**~/.ssh content : robstat.pem**

**Network : Having home wifi with 192.168.1.1 local address and is connected to broadband connection from my ISP**

**deleted `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file in which everything was commented. I tried uncommenting port 20 but all in vain. Didn't touch and know about `sshd_config` file at all. Unistalled and the installed `openssh` once. The key pair `AWS.pem` was created and downloading from AWS and I did it chmod 400**

**I pinged my instance. It just printed one line with 84 bytes substring but not like 64 bytes...64bytes that we get when we ping another LAN system.**

**I just ssh-ed into my raspeberry pi running Ubuntu mate and it was a successful. I nmap-ed in both OSes to find out that port 22 is of type ssh in both of them.**

**2) My AWS :-**

**firstly created an IAM user and gave it the permissions under a user group and then by signing in into the console with this IMA, I launch my AMI 64 bit instance. I have created the key, the same that is downloaded in my system and I always launch the micro instance using the same key.**

**The VPC is only one (default) and the security get autocreated with the creation of wizard that has inbound rule as ssh - tcp - 22 - everywhere and the outgoing is all traffic to everyone**

**I always connect by clicking on the connect icon above the running instance and then copy that and by cd to .ssh directory, I run the command for ssh with the key name in double quotes and -v for debugging but it ends at connection time out. output -**

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ec2-18-218-85-233.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-18-218-85-233.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com [18.218.85.233] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 18.218.85.233 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-18-218-85-233.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

P.S. I have also implemented [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html) guide many number of times with my understanding from the context but I'm messed up.

Comment: To ping your EC2 instance you need to allow ICMP-IPV4 into security group.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the Network ACLs as well.
Also, you can check "Instance settings" - "Get System Log", and watch what happens inside the instance.
Do you have access if you run a new instance?

Comment: Yup and I will try in a day or two again (there is nothing about incoming ssh connection in the instance's log) and I will get back to you. Hope I will be able to solve it in the comment section.